# Column high chart 'stacking:normal' with boost js file

Tags: highcharts

I am facing issue while rendering the data in column chart around 9000 (thousand) points with *'stacking:normal'* and its taking too much time to load the data in IE and Chrome(taking around 5-12 secs each time when i request the data from server in paging mode) but when i comment the *'stacking:normal'* it works fine and quite fast and taking less than 2 secs. but my requirement with *'stacking:normal'*.

Any suggestion how i can resolve the issue and optimize the performance ?
Please check the below fiddler here you can find the data format.

[`live demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/fa79n3yt/6/)

I checked the performance in chrome and found the below result. will wait for the reply.

[`See chrome perfomance results screenshot`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE9p1.png)

Comment: here the fiddle link you can view the data there.. http://jsfiddle.net/fa79n3yt/6/

Comment: On my machine everything works fine in Chrome (about 0,5 s to render), but in Explorer rendering lasts 7,5 s or so. You can report it as an issue here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues

Comment: Thanks for reply, now issue is with data grouping as we need sum.of the column values when I comment that line insteadof stacking then it works fine but column values in tooltip got messed up....

Comment: I don't quite understand how to reproduce this issue. Please provide live working demo and the detailed explanations of what is wrong with the tooltip.

Comment: Thanks for reply Kamil.

Let me clear you now that I am rendering the data around 10000 (10 thousand points) each time (weekly data) and due to dataGrouping with stacking taking time to render the chart. its taking 3-5 sec in chrome and 10+ secs in IE. How can we improve the performance using data Grouping? or any another alternative ? 
Please check the below fiddler.

http://jsfiddle.net/fa79n3yt/11/

Comment: I see that the same discussion takes place on Highcharts forum: https://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/column-highchart-stacking-normal-with-boost-js-t39975/ Let's continue it there.